# Uniform Convergence when $\lim f(x)$ does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I can't find any similar questions online (except it might just be a bit too wordy), but say you are given a function:

$f_n(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^n}, x \in \mathbb{R}$

And the limit of $f_n(x)$ does not exist for x = -1 (and $n$ is odd), is this a sufficient reason for it to not uniformly converge (or even pointwise converge)?

I'm presuming the answer is yes but would just like a confirmation. It makes sense since the definition of uniform convergence is:

Given $\epsilon > 0 \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\forall n>n. \left| f_n(x)-f(x) \right| < \epsilon$

But this is impossible if $f(x)$ is undefined.

So in short: if there is an $x$ value for which $f_n(x) \rightarrow f$ is undefined, then $f_n(x)$ cannot (uniformly) converge.

Comment: Obviously if that function is not defined at x=1 for any odd n... But is it your intention to know whether the functions $f_n=1/(1+x^{2n+1})$ are uniformly convergent on the open interval (-1,1)?

Comment: There's a rather significant difference

Comment: The first part of the question asks for the uniform convergence on the interval [0, 1]. I am assuming it would not, since the limit is 1 for x in (-1,1) (also answering your above question - it would be uniformly convergent on the interval you suggested) and the limit is 0, for abs(x) > 1, and $\lim = \frac{1}{2}$ for $x = 1$. It wouldn't be uniform on the interval [0,1] anyway since the limit 'jumps' around multiple times. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it doesn't converge pointwise at -1, and subsequently the sequence doesn't converge uniformly on the set that includes -1.

check your quantifiers, too, in your definition of uniform convergence.

you should have, right after epsilon positive, "for all x in the set ... "

this asserts that the convergence is independent of the choice of x.